# Why can't I check my version of GCC compiler on OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, gcc

I typed this in my terminal:

`llvm-gcc --version`

But what I have is this :

```
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix`
```

Am I not able to interpret this block of statements? or did I forget to enable something on my system?

Comment: Did you try, for example, "gcc --version"?

Comment: Mac OS X no longer uses gcc at all. The [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) compiler is used by default.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing is wrong. The situation is just a little confusing.

Apple no longer distributes GCC with Xcode. They now use [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) as the default (and only!) compiler on Mac OS X. `cc`, `gcc`, and `clang` (as well as the C++ variants, `c++`, `g++`, and `clang++`) are now all linked to run clang under current versions of Xcode.

The version of clang you're running is, per the `--version` output, 500.2.79.

If you want to install GCC as an alternative to clang, you can do so using a variety of methods, including one using Homebrew:

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Custom-GCC-and-cross-compilers

Comment: Tell us how to determine the version of gcc on a system that still uses it.

Comment: according to `man gcc` - ***In Apple's version of GCC***, both cc and gcc are actually symbolic links to the ***llvm-gcc*** compiler. Similarly, c++ and g++ are links to llvm-g++. ***Note that Apple's GCC includes a number of extensions to standard GCC*** (flagged below with "APPLE ONLY"), and that not all generic GCC options are available or supported on Darwin / Mac OS X., so regardless of apple's version it's still considered ***gcc***

Comment: @l'L'l: This is not the case on current versions of Mac OS X and the developer tools — the manual page is out of date. The binaries at `/usr/bin/cc`, `/usr/bin/gcc`, *et al* are now all stub binaries which link to `/usr/lib/libxcselect.dylib`, which launches the appropriate binary from your active Xcode installation.

Comment: — true, gcc has been replaced on 10.9, although to argue that `gcc -v` does not return the version information on OS X prior to 10.9 (if gcc is present) is simply wrong. GCC = `GNU Compiler Collection`, and according to their website The GNU Compiler Collection includes front ends for C, C++, Objective-C, Fortran, Java, Ada, and Go, as well as libraries for these languages (libstdc++, libgcj,...). GCC was originally written as the compiler for the GNU operating system.

Comment: Prior to OS X 10.9 Apple developed their own version of gcc (mine happens to be 4.2.1), which contains extensions from the standard gcc 4.2.1. Do this make sense?

Comment: Yes - I've been using Mac OS X for a very long time, and I'm quite aware of this. However, **that's not the version the OP is using**. The version string in the question, with "clang" appearing in the first line and "gcc" absent, indicates that the OP is running Clang, not GCC.

Comment: Is there any more information about this mechanism? @duskwuff